# iOS NSURLConnection fails when switching tab directly from appDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurlconnection

I have an app with several tabs, and the one in the middle contains images. I want my app to jump to the second tab inside a tab bar controller when the user clicks on a certain URL,loading a new image into the view.
It works perfectly if the app is already opened. But it fails if the app was killed and has to be opened again. I think NSURL connection fails to load as quick as it should.

I use this code inside the app delegate for switching the tab:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    NSLog("Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication!)

    if (url.scheme != nil){
        scheme = url.scheme!
    }

    if (url.query != nil){
        query = url.query
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let statusViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("statuscontrollerid") as! StatusController

    let tabController = self.window!.rootViewController as! TabBarController
    tabController.selectedIndex = 1
```

And I register the second view controller as observer to load a certain URL as soon as it becomes a notification that the app become active.

SecondViewController's code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //loadDefaultURLS()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "readURLParameters", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}


func readURLParameters(){

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    if appDelegate.scheme != nil {
        self.scheme = appDelegate.scheme
    }

    if appDelegate.query != nil{
        let urlstring = NSURL(string:appDelegate.query)
        self.graphsURLlist.append(urlstring!)
        //self.pageImages.addObject(NSNull)
        self.pageImages.addObject(UIImage(named: "needToSynchronize.png")!)

        self.pageControl.numberOfPages++
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        self.downloadImagesfromUrlArray()
        appDelegate.scheme = nil
        appDelegate.query = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is being invoked at the right time to be able to be able for `readURLParameters` to respond?

I think wait until `viewDidLoad` in `SecondViewController`,  and just call your `readURLParameters` method from there.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the readURLParameters, it fails because of switching in the app delegate to the second tab. I loop throughout the array and download the content once everything is loaded in viewDidAppear, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Anyone had similar problems? It's been 4 days and I still don't get it